# Android background process hang UI

Tags: android, asynchronous

In my asynctask i am updating UI of `onPostExecute()`. My UI components are created dynamically and set in for loop.

As it is so much heavy UI operation i am getting message like "`Application not responding`" with option "`close`" or "`wait".

I have tried to run that operation in runonUI and even in new async. But it gives the message.

Comment: @Itzik: It only updateUI in postexhicute() and UI is heavy. UI having FAQ que and answers.

Comment: Post your code, it's impossible to answer without it.

Comment: I guess you are performing client-server request/response. Thats why your app gets stopped. You need to go for Service Handler. i.e. best way to do so

Comment: This generally (obviously) isn't supposed to happen, so the solution will depend on whatever in your code is causing this. So yes, we need to see your code to see what the issue is.